# Why is the play store displaying same app twice under the My apps section

Tags: google-play-store, bugs

[image: Under the All apps the true caller is shown twice by the play store] [image: Under the settings there is only one app not two.][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SruHR.png)
<sup>Under the All apps the true caller is shown twice by the play store / Under the settings there is only one app not two. (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Android Version:4.1.2 Jellybean

Device: Samsung Trend Duos.

In the above image the True Caller application is shown twice and both are of the same  no extra app on(or plugin for that particular app). I have force closed the application ,later switched the device waited for some time and restarted the device and still the application duplicate is displayed under My apps.

There are not two apps as you can see in the downloads section.(The applications list is sorted name wise so there's no chance of missing a second true caller app)

Comment: Two things to check: 1) have you installed the app on multiple devices (shouldn't be the reason for that, but is the first thing coming to mind) and 2) have you checked in *Settings→Apps* on your device if you have two apps of the same name (also unlikely, as the playstore only seems to have that once – but sometimes, the "free" and the "paid" version of an app have the same "display name")?

Comment: There is  only a single Application with the name and True Caller is free there's no paid version for that

Comment: @Izzy there's only 1 single application under the settings>apps

Comment: I've just read about a similar case; there uninstalling and re-installing solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The publisher of this app may have changed their package name when updating the app. Usually, apps have the same package name for its entire lifetime, which is how the phone knows to update a current app instead of installing a new one. If this is the case, you should uninstall the old app. The quickest (and easiest) fix is to uninstall both and reinstall the latest version. Provided the app's package name doesn't change again during the next update, this should solve your issue.

Comment: Just to clarify: You can't change the package name with an Play Store update. But you can release a new version of an App under a new/changed package name.

Answer (score 0):

i encountered the same problem yesterday but then today when i checked google play to check the rankings of my app, the issue was sorted out. As the google is doing massive changes so i reckon it was a fault from google side.

i have read the above conversation and just for record to clear for others in desktop there is no such scenario of free and paid. it only occurs in cellphones :)